# Google Colab local runtime connecting error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

I want to connect Google Colab to my local jupyter runtime. I installed the below extension as suggested by colab.

```
pip install --upgrade jupyter_http_over_ws>=0.0.7 && jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws
```

Then I run the command and started a jupyter notebook. After that I try to connect google colab to the local runtime with the prompted URL. But then I got the follow issue. Please help me to solve this.

```
F:\Education\SEMESTER 7\CO421 FINAL YEAR PROJECT\PROJECT\josh>jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'--port=8888 --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
jupyter_http_over_ws extension initialized. Listening on /http_over_websocket
[I 12:01:45.043 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: F:\Education\SEMESTER 7\CO421 FINAL YEAR PROJECT\PROJECT\josh
[I 12:01:45.043 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.4 is running at:
[I 12:01:45.043 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=9308f0fdb2a8ebe003eec56aa2684dfb7c51c873ba0d9214
[I 12:01:45.043 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=9308f0fdb2a8ebe003eec56aa2684dfb7c51c873ba0d9214
[I 12:01:45.043 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 12:01:45.125 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/prasa/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-6268-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=9308f0fdb2a8ebe003eec56aa2684dfb7c51c873ba0d9214
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=9308f0fdb2a8ebe003eec56aa2684dfb7c51c873ba0d9214
[W 12:02:15.646 NotebookApp] Blocking Cross Origin API request for /http_over_websocket.  Origin: https://colab.research.google.com, Host: localhost:8888
[W 12:02:15.647 NotebookApp] 403 GET /http_over_websocket?min_version=0.0.7&jupyter_http_over_ws_auth_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2F%3Ftoken%3D5d6bb0b08b718df4fMUpVa4LvtUpaHGkcUqPkMpyiaoG8817 (::1) 2.99ms referer=None
```